# Connecting to a mongodb cluster in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, terraform, linode

I have this terraform config for creating a single mongodb replica and a service but I can't connect to mongo using the cli and the cluster domain name.

```
locals {
  labels = {
    "app" = "mongo"
  }
  volume_config_name = "mongo-config"
}

module "mongo" {
  source  = "terraform-iaac/stateful-set/kubernetes"
  version = "1.4.2"
  # insert the 3 required variables here
  image     = "mongo:4.4"
  name      = "mongodb"
  namespace = kubernetes_namespace.cmprimg.metadata[0].name

  custom_labels = local.labels

  volume_host_path = [
    {
      volume_name  = "data"
      path_on_node = "/data/db"
    },
  ]
  volume_mount = [
    {
      mount_path  = "/data/db"
      volume_name = "data"
    },
    {
      mount_path  = "/etc/mongod.conf.orig"
      volume_name = "mongodb-conf"
      sub_path    = "configfile" // Key from configmap
    }
  ]

  volume_config_map = [{
    mode        = "0777"
    volume_name = "mongodb-conf"
    name        = "mongodb-confmap"
  }]

  # volume_claim = [
  #   {
  #     name                   = "mongo"
  #     namespace              = kubernetes_namespace.cmprimg.metadata[0].name
  #     access_modes           = ["ReadWriteOnce"]
  #     requests_storage       = "4Gi"
  #     persistent_volume_name = "mongo"
  #     storage_class_name     = "linode-block-storage-retain"
  #   }
  # ]
  env = {
    "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" = var.username,
    "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" = var.password,
  }
  command = [
    "mongod",
    "--bind_ip",
    "0.0.0.0",
  ]

  internal_port = [
    {
      name          = "mongo"
      internal_port = 27017
    }
  ]

  resources = {
    request_cpu    = "100m"
    request_memory = "800Mi"
    limit_cpu      = "120m"
    limit_memory   = "900Mi"
  }

  replicas = 1
}

module "mongo_service" {
  source  = "terraform-iaac/service/kubernetes"
  version = "1.0.4"
  # insert the 3 required variables here

  app_name      = module.mongo.name
  app_namespace = kubernetes_namespace.cmprimg.metadata[0].name
  port_mapping = [
    {
      name          = "mongo"
      internal_port = 27107
      external_port = 27017
    }
  ]

  custom_labels = local.labels
}

resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim" "example" {
  metadata {
    name      = "mongo"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.cmprimg.metadata[0].name
    labels    = local.labels
  }

  spec {
    access_modes = ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    resources {
      requests = {
        storage = "20Gi"
      }
    }
    storage_class_name = "linode-block-storage-retain"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_config_map" "mongodb_conf" {
  metadata {
    name      = "mongodb-confmap"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.cmprimg.metadata[0].name
    labels    = local.labels
  }

  data = {
    "configfile" = yamlencode({
      storage : {
        dbPath : "/data/db",
      },
      net : {
        port : 27017,
        bindIp : "0.0.0.0",
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I can exec into the mongodb pod and use mongo cli to connect using localhost, but when I'm in the same pod and use mongocli to connect using the domain name `mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017` I get connection refused. I can see in the logs that mongodb binds to `0.0.0.0` but can't connect through external ports. Did I misconfigure the service or do something else wrong?

Comment: in which namespace mongodb is deployed?

Comment: @blakelead `default`, I already confirmed its not a namespace issue

Comment: I'm not familiar with the module you use to create the service. is the selector configuration correctly generated?

Comment: @blakelead when I look at the service in the dashboard I see the mongodb pod listed as an endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at this section:

```
port_mapping = [
  {
    name          = "mongo"
    internal_port = 27107
    external_port = 27017
  }
]
```

1. You use „internal” and „external” port numbers inconsistently across file (the internal here is 27**10**7)
2. Are you sure the syntax of this block is correct? In the reaserch I made through the Internet the portMappings section has usually different syntax (e.g. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/21861)

.

```
portMappings = [
  {
      containerPort = var.container_port
      hostPort = var.container_port
      protocol = "tcp"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I didn't even notice that typo, thank you.